# Salt: connection refused to proxy

Tags: proxy, centos7, yum, saltstack

I have troubles with Salt, installed on an HPC cluster. All maintenance commands (i.e. salt commands) are made from `master0`. The minions to be managed are named `node0`, `node1`, ..., `node4`. When I try to install a package on a minion (let's say python's numpy on `node0`), I get the following error:

```
[root@master0 ~]# salt 'node0' pkg.install python3-numpy
  *duplicate lines removed*
https://vault.centos.org/7.8.2003/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to master0:3142; Connection refused"
```

On `node0`, file `/etc/yum.conf` looks like this:

```
[main]
exclude=ibutils-libs*
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
proxy=http://master0:3142
```

As far as I understand, `node0` does not manage to connect to `master0` through port 3142. Indeed, I can curl `master0` on default port (80 I guess), but not on 3142:

```
[root@node0 ~]# curl 'http://master0:3142'
curl: (7) Failed connect to master0:3142; Connection refused
[root@node0 ~]# curl 'http://master0'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  *Some HTML stuff, not relevant here*
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't get where I am supposed to *open* this port on `master0`.

*Note: Complete newbie here. To be honest, I don't get the point of passing through this port either, but the whole HPC structure was built by an external service provider, and I just try to handle all this stuff by my own.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a proxy, just remove the `proxy=` line from your `yum.conf`.

Alternatively, start your proxy server.

3142 is the default port of apt-cacher, which is used for Debian based distributions, but can also be used to cache RPM packages.

Your config indicates that it used to run on `master0` (or you skipped steps you deemed irrelevant when following a tutorial).

Comment: This ridiculously works! I feel a little dumb now... What's the purpose of using a proxy here?

Comment: Actually, I though the proxy was mandatory because all traffic from minions pass through ``master0``, as evidenced by ``[root@node0 ~]# traceroute google.fr`` for example.

Comment: The purpose of the proxy is that not every node needs to download the package from the official mirror, but from a local mirror (the proxy) instead.